# Как компилятор может быть написан на том же языке который он компилирует?

Tags: ассемблер, компиляция, трансляция

Прочитал несколько подобных вопросов но так и не нашел полноценного ответа.
Как компилятор Си может быть написан на Си, ведь кто-то должен скомпилировать сам компилятор в машинный код. И будет ли трансляция в ассемблер по сути равна компиляции? (за исключением того что команды ассемблера нужно будет потом заменить на двоичный код)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Компилятор си написан на предыдущей версии компилятора. Но когда то давно-давно существовал момент, когда компилятор си был написан на чем то другом. Я к сожалению, не знаю этого момента.

Но вот с плюсовым компилятором все проще - вначале был написан cfront - программа на си, которая переводила "плюсовый код" в сишный, а потом уже компилировала.

С другими языками также такое происходило. К примеру, go был вначале написан на си, а потом код так модифицировали, что бы он был максимально похож на go код (https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/5652).

Поэтому, с чистым си компилятором для x86 скорее всего было так - в какой то момент просто для доступной на тот момент платформы взяли си компилятор и поправили кодогенерацию. И готово. И у нас уже генерируются бинарники для новый платформы.

Но как появился самый первый компилятор тогда? Есть хорошая статья https://jameshfisher.com/2018/01/11/bootstrapping-a-c-compiler/ которая описывает, как поэтапно можно это сделать.

А здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65751457/how-could-one-possibly-bootstrap-a-c-compilerfrom-source спрашивают почти то же, что и Вы.

То есть, вначале все пишется ручками в памяти, в ноликах и единицах, потом постепенно наращиваются инструменты и в конце концов, такими итерациями можно дойти до современного мира. Вот люди пишут простейший си компилятор https://github.com/rdtscp/c-bootstrap

> И будет ли трансляция в ассемблер по сути равна компиляции

если у нас есть компилятор ассемблера, то да. Почему "компилятор"? потому что ассемблеры бывают разные. Тот же [FLAT assembler](https://flatassembler.net/) обладает таким разувесистым синтаксисом, что я бы побоялся его называть его компилятор "программой для замены на двоичный код".

Да, процесс, когда компилятор компилирует сам себя называется bootstrapping. и это не имеет отношения к html.

Comment: Вот [сорсы первого C](https://github.com/mortdeus/legacy-cc), которые транслировались [компилятором, написанным на B, который в свою очередь начался с программы на BCPL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18126181/7286264) / [Вот тут](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html) Dennis M. Ritchie описывает эту историю

Comment: Кстати, это уже насколько я сам помню, первый gcc был написан RMS на UCLI (University of California Leadership Institute) Pascal

Comment: @KoVadim т.е. я правильно понял что есть какая то часть функционала языка которая заранее скомпилирована например из си в ассемблер, и далее с помощью этой части мы уже дописываем основной компилятор для основной части языка?

Comment: да, постепенно наращиваем функционал.